# Expressing assertions more naturally

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, assertions

Suppose I write a function

```
f [x, y] = x + y
f [x, y, z] = z - x - y
```

This is filled out by the compiler with an extra line saying something like

```
f _ = error "pattern match failed"
```

If `f` is not exported, and I *know* it's only applied properly, and the function is performance-critical, I may want to avoid having an extra pattern in the production code. I could rewrite this rather unnaturally something like

```
f l = assert (atLeastTwo l) $
        let (x,r1) = (unsafeHead l, unsafeTail l) in
          let (y,r2) = (unsafeHead r1, unsafeTail r1) in
            case r2 of
              [] -> x + y
              (z,r3) -> assert (r3 == []) $ z - x - y
```

What I'd *like* to do is write the original function definition with an extra line:

```
f _ = makeDemonsComeOutOfMyNose "This error is impossible."
```

The descriptively named magical function would be compiled as `error` when assertions or inferred safe Haskell are enabled, and marked as unreachable (rendering the pattern match unsafe) when assertions are disabled. Is there a way to do this, or something similar?

#### Edit

To address jberryman's concerns about whether there is a real performance impact:

1. This is a hypothetical question. I suspect that in more complicated cases, where there are multiple "can't happen" cases, there is likely to be a performance benefit—at the least, error cases can use extra space in the instruction cache.
2. Even if there *isn't* a real performance issue, I think there's also an *expressive* distinction between an assertion and an error. I suspect the most flexible assertion form is "this code should be unreachable", perhaps with an argument or three indicating how seriously the compiler should take that claim. Safety is relative—if a data structure invariant is broken and causes the program to leak confidential information, that's not necessarily any less serious than an invalid memory access. Note that, roughly speaking, `assert p x = if p then x else makeDemonsFlyOutOfMyNose NO_REAL_DEMONS_PLEASE "assertion failed"`, but there's no way to define the demon function in terms of `assert`.

Comment: You just want to do this for performance reasons? Have you been able to measure the effects of an extra case calling error before?

Comment: Also, what is the performance cost of a case that isn't ever reached?

Comment: Because you're using linked-lists, that level of perfomance consideration should be out. C-like last-resort optimisations (which, I don't need [to remind you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed_bug), should _really_ be last-resort!) only make sense if you also avoid the cache misses inherent to any non-consecutive-memory data structure.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, this is a *hypothetical* example.

Comment: @jberryman, I think I've addressed your concerns in my edit.

Comment: I doubt this would be possible. Haskell is designed to be memory safe when using the core language.

Comment: I don't understand #2 in your edit; maybe you can elaborate?

Comment: @jozefg, Haskell is *not* memory safe in the presence of `unsafePerformIO`, `unsafeInterleaveST`, unsafe vector indexing, etc.".

Comment: @jberryman, assertions don't fit with complicated patterns or nested logic very well. In simple cases, you can write something like `f x = assert (p x) $ f' x`, but if you have something complicated and you stick to this pattern, then the code for `p` may duplicate a bunch of the code in `f'`, which is ugly and time-consuming. The alternative I can think of is to decompose the pattern matching into multiple layers and weave assertions into them, but this is even uglier.

Answer (score 3):

GHC is clever enough to optimize the unused pattern match away. Here's a simple program.

```
module Foo (foo) where

data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

link :: List a -> List a -> List a
link Nil        _   = error "link: Nil"
link (Cons a _) xs  = Cons a xs

l1 = Cons 'a' (Cons 'b' Nil)

foo = link l1
```

This is a very contrived example, but it demonstrates the case where GHC can prove that `link` (or in your case `f`) is being called on a statically known constructor (or can otherwise prove which pattern match will succeed via inlining, simplifying etc.)

And here's the Core output:

```
foo1 :: Char
foo1 = C# 'a'

foo :: List Char -> List Char
foo = \ (ds :: List Char) -> Cons foo1 ds
```

The `error` case doesn't show up anywhere in the Core for `Foo`. So you can be assured that in cases like this, there is absolutely no performance difference incurred by having an extra unused pattern match.

Comment: This is rather *too* simple, I think. The sort of use-case I'm thinking of is a module implementing a data structure with some invariant that should be checked by assertions. Inlining won't help with that, because the data structure and the operations to be performed on it are not known statically.

Comment: Well, your question asks (among other things) how GHC treats unused pattern matches and I've shown here that unused pattern matches can be optimized away entirely. If you're instead asking how to maintain invariants of data structures without runtime overhead, then you may be able to express those invariants at the type level which will then have no overhead at runtime. What kind of data structure, and what invariant are you thinking of specifically?